# undefined method `password' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error when I try to get to the users#login page.
my controller is

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
# GET /users
# GET /users.json
def login
@username = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
@password = params[:password]
if(@username.password == @password)
  format.json { render json: @username, notice: "Login Successful!!" }
end
end

def index
@users = User.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @user }
end
end

# GET /users/1
# GET /users/1.json
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @user }
end
end

# GET /users/new
# GET /users/new.json
def new
@user = User.new

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @user }
end
end

# GET /users/1/edit
def edit
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end

# POST /users
# POST /users.json
def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
 end

# PUT /users/1
# PUT /users/1.json
def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# DELETE /users/1
# DELETE /users/1.json
def destroy
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user.destroy

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to users_url }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end
end
```

I researched and the problems people had was that either they didnt migrate the column "password" or there password was actually "Password" but when i get into rails console and run

```
user = User.new
 => #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, username: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at:     nil, password: nil>
```

so I guess that is not my problem.

Comment: Your `@username` must be nil. Can you show us the form which is triggering the `login`?

Comment: actually i am using this as a backend server for my iphone app(which is not ready yet). how do i go about checking if my login action actually works without my app?Ohh and to get to the login I just put in the address in the address bar, is that wrong?

Comment: Your `login` action is expecting params. You should first determine what sort of param-hash is this method obtaining.

Comment: what do you mean by "what sort of params"?

Comment: I mean, is it really getting `params = {"username" => "foobar", "password" => "boofar"}` or not. Or is nested?

Comment: ohh, it is not nested. It expects a json format and now i understand why i get this error because i dont send in any params, although how do I send in params without my client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are not getting the record of user from database. There is two possibilities

1) Either the user is not in database or

2) The parameter is wrong i.e. params[:username]

You need to check that parameter is coming as expected and if its correct then try to look at the database that record is available.

You can check params like this:

```
puts params[:username]
puts params[:password]
```

Or you can also check from server console.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `@username` is `nil`. `@username` is a confusing name anyway, it should be `@user`.